# Create a new variable based in conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to create (mutate) a new variable in a database but I am having some problems. My idea is to create a variable that replicates the result of another variable in the database conditioned on the value of a previous variable.

Let me show an example:

```
Database
var1var2var3    var4
1   45  AH67    A456
1   78  GH98    D788
5   46  GD94    M747
5   98  GF21    G589
10  47  GD09    I989
10  54  KG32    U456
15  48  FS89    C191
15  66  GF23    Y198
```

My idea is:

- If var1=1, new=var2
- If var1=5, new=var3
- If var1=10, new=NA.
- If var1=15, new=var4

Expected result:

```
var1var2var3    var4    new
1   45  AH67    A456    45
1   78  GH98    D788    78
5   46  GD94    M747    GD94
5   98  GF21    G589    GD94
10  47  GD09    I989    na
10  54  KG32    U456    na
15  48  FS89    C191    C191
15  66  GF23    Y198    Y198
```

I tried this but it didn’t work out.

```
data<-mutate(data,
             ifelse(var1==1){New=var2},
             ifelse(var1==5){New=var3},
             ifelse(var1==10){New=NA},
             ifelse(var1==15){New=var4})
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `mutate` is `mutate(.data, new_col = something)`. Also, since you have multiple condition based on `var1`, you'll need to have a nested `ifelse`. Therefore, the correct way of doing it is:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(new = ifelse(var1 == 1, 
                           var2, 
                           ifelse(var1 == 5, 
                                  var3, 
                                  ifelse(var1 == 10, 
                                         NA, 
                                         ifelse(var1 == 15, 
                                                var4, 
                                                NA)))))
```

Or use `dplyr::case_when`, which is way clearer in the syntax:

```
df %>% mutate(new = case_when(var1 == 1 ~ as.character(var2),
                              var1 == 5 ~ var3,
                              var1 == 15 ~ var4))
```

### Output

The output of the above two methods are the same.

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4  new
1    1   45 AH67 A456   45
2    1   78 GH98 D788   78
3    5   46 GD94 M747 GD94
4    5   98 GF21 G589 GF21
5   10   47 GD09 I989 <NA>
6   10   54 KG32 U456 <NA>
7   15   48 FS89 C191 C191
8   15   66 GF23 Y198 Y198
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%  
  mutate(new = case_when(var1 == 1 ~ as.character(var2),
                         var1 == 5 ~ var3,
                         var1 == 10 ~ as.character(NA),
                         var1 == 15 ~ var4))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   var1  var2 var3  var4  new  
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1    45 AH67  A456  45   
2     1    78 GH98  D788  78   
3     5    46 GD94  M747  GD94 
4     5    98 GF21  G589  GF21 
5    10    47 GD09  I989  NA   
6    10    54 KG32  U456  NA   
7    15    48 FS89  C191  C191 
8    15    66 GF23  Y198  Y198
```

Comment: Nice job! But next time when there's a same answer already posted, you don't need to post it again :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I see we worked on that at the same time. I decided to post anyway because of the difference of `as.character(NA)` that sometimes is a headache to input missing with `case_when()`

Comment: Totally understood! No need to apologise for that :) But in this case, the `var1 == 10 ~ as.character(NA)` is redundant, since the output for no match is already NA :) Totally understand your point :)

Comment: True. However, I often like to state in my syntax everything that is happening. That helps me troubleshoot things later because I’m still in my learning phase. Thanks anyway for the tips for the future. ;)